# Uniform convergence of the product without uniform-absolute convergence of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

Consider a sequence of functions $a_n:A \subset \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ (note nonnegativity) such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $A$ but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x)$ converges pointwise but **not** uniformly on $A$.  An example is $a_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$ with $A = [0,1)$.

What can we say about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(\,1+(-1)^na_n(x)\,\right)$ and equivalently $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (\,1 + (-1)^na_n(x)\,)$?  Must the convergence be uniform or if not what is  a counterexample -- $a_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$ perhaps?

**Some context:** In every presentation on uniform convergence of infinite products I have seen there is a theorem:

> If the series $\sum |a_n(x)|$ is uniformly convergent, then so too is
> $\prod (1 + a_n(x)).$

The proof is straightforward, noting that $0 < |a_n(x)| < 1/2$ for sufficiently large $n$ and

$$|\log(1+a_n(x)| \leqslant |a_n(x)| + \frac{1}{2}|a_n(x)|^2 + \frac{1}{3} |a_n(x)|^3 + \ldots \leqslant \frac{|a_n(x)|}{1-  |a_n(x)|} \leqslant 2 |a_n(x)|$$

However, nothing is said about the case where $\sum a_n(x)$ is uniformly and absolutely convergent but not uniformly-absolutely convergent -- that is, $\sum a_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent, $\sum |a_n(x)|$ is convergent, but $\sum|a_n(x)|$ is not uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your example $a_k(x)=\frac {x^{k}} k$ on $[0,\infty)$ instead of $[0,1]$.

$t-\log (1+t)\geq \frac 1 3t^{2}$ for $|t|$ sufficently small. Note that $a_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly. So we can put $t=(-1)^{n}a_n(x)$ in above inequality if $n$ is sufficiently large. Suppose $\sum \log (1+(-1)^{n})a_n(x)$ converges uniformly. Then our inequality implies that $\sum a_n (x)^{2}$ converges uniformly but this is false. Hence  $\sum \log (1+(-1)^{n})a_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Thanks, but I think $t - \log(1+t) < \frac{1}{2}t^2$ for small $t > 0$.  There is an inflection point in $t - \log(1+t) - \frac{1}{2}t^2$ at $t=0$.  SInce $(-1)^na_n(x)$ changes sign this brings me back to problems I had on my own.

Comment: @RRL $\frac {t-\log (1+t)} {t^{2}} \to \frac  1 2$ as $ t \to 0$. So $t-\log (1+t) \geq \frac 1  3 t^{2}$ for $|t|$ sufficiently small. I have changed $\frac 1 2$ to $\frac 1 3$ and I think my proof works fine now.

Comment: That fixes the inequality and it would seem the argument leads to $\sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k(x)|^2 \leqslant 3\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^m (-1)^ka_k(x)\right| + 3 \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^m \log(1 + (-1)^ka_k(x))\right| $.  That leads to a contradiction of the Cauchy criterion if the series on the LHS is not uniformly convergent.  It does not help with the specific example $a_k(x) = x^k/k$ on $[0,1)$ because $|a_k(x)|^2 \leqslant 1/k^2$ and $\sum |a_k(x)|^2$ converges uniformly by the M test.

Comment: However, using this idea I can find $a_k(x) = x^k/\sqrt{k}$ as a counterexample.  Thanks.